# HA proxy grouping requests

Tags: load-balancing, distributed-computing, distributed, haproxy

I am using HA proxy as the load balancer.
I have specified two nodes for load balancing in round robin fashion. The things are  working fine if i post request manually i can see that the req is getting routed to each node in a round robin fashion. When i use curl to fire some 5000 req then i see the that around 100 req are going to one node and then 100 to another another node. so it is not alternating based on req. I dont think this is the correct beahviour. Is there some config which i need to change ?
or is it curl behaviour?

```
curl -k  <url>?name=[1-5000]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're directing curl to make sequential requests with an incrementing counter, with those numbers in brackets in the [URL](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#URL), and curl is going to reuse the connection to HAProxy, via http keep-alive.

HAProxy is also going to reuse the connection to the backend by default, because that's the most efficient behavior, avoiding the overhead of estsblishing a new TCP connection.  There's no reason to artificially force a round robin distribution when all the requests are coming from a single client on a reused connection, with a concurrency of 1.

You can force a change to this behavior with one of several options, but it should be unnecessary since this is primarily an artifact of your test methodology.

> By default HAProxy operates in keep-alive mode with regards to persistent
>   connections: for each connection it processes each request and response, and
>   leaves the connection idle on both sides between the end of a response and
>   the start of a new request. This mode may be changed by several options such
>   as "option http-server-close", "option forceclose", "option httpclose" or
>   "option http-tunnel". Setting "option http-server-close" enables HTTP
>   connection-close mode on the server side while keeping the ability to support
>   HTTP keep-alive and pipelining on the client side.  This provides the lowest
>   latency on the client side (slow network) and the fastest session reuse on
>   the server side to save server resources, similarly to "option forceclose".
>   It also permits non-keepalive capable servers to be served in keep-alive mode
>   to the clients if they conform to the requirements of RFC7230. Please note
>   that some servers do not always conform to those requirements when they see
>   "Connection: close" in the request. The effect will be that keep-alive will
>   never be used. A workaround consists in enabling "option
>   http-pretend-keepalive".
>
> http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4-option%20http-server-close

So why does it alternate every ~100?  Keep-alive connections can't usually be used indefinitely, so either the client or the server will eventially close the connection and a new one will be established.